# CORS error while accessing a url with basic authentication from localhost with fetch JS

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, basic-authentication

I am trying to access an API endpoint `GET https://example.com/data`.
The endpoint has basic authentication and here is how I tried to call the endpoint at first:

```
const credentials = btoa("username:password");
fetch(fullUrl, {method: callMethod,
        credentials: "include",
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`,
        }),
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => console.log("There is an error:", error))
```

This got me cors error as follows:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/data' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Then, I used mode: 'no-cors' as suggested as follows:

```
const credentials = btoa("username:password");
fetch(fullUrl, {
        mode:  'no-cors',
        method: callMethod,
        credentials: "include",
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`,
        }),
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => console.log("There is an error:", error))
```

This allowed me to access the endpoint by entering the username and password through pop-up in browser but then the response was not as desired and I could not access the response text. However in network tab I can see that we are getting 200 response status code along with desired response. The response as in console was as follows:

```
Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
```

My main objective is to remove CORS error by using username and password through code and not having to type username and password through pop-up window. And if I have to then access the response I see in network tab and not the opaque response that I receive when using no-cors mode.

Comment: `I used mode: 'no-cors' as suggested as follows:` no-cors is useful if you don't need to read the response - note, the *suggestion* states *If an opaque response serves your needs* - clearly not the case for your requirements!! Your best bet is to make the request through *your server* - that's the only way to *fix* CORS *errors* - I would suggest looking for the youtube video titles "Learn CORS in 6 minutes" if you want to know what CORS even is

Comment: Because you're explicitly specifying an `Authorization` header in your request, you cannot send that request in `no-cors` mode.

Answer (score 1):

What you want works only if the endpoint explicitly allows the `Authorization` header in CORS requests. The browser will make a preflight request

```
OPTIONS https://example.com/data
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization
```

to which the endpoint must respond with

```
200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

If you control the endpoint, you can achieve this, for example, with the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package in case of a Node.js endpoint.

But if the endpoint is controlled by someone else, that person has decided that they do not want to be called with basic authentication from a web page with different origin, and you cannot circumvent that. You can then only make the desired call from a web server that you control.